# how to send image file from pc to wifi tablet using C# windows application

Tags: c#

I am new to c#,I want to send an Image file from PC to wifi tablet and also how to open that image file in tablet using c# windows application.
anyone can help?
thanx

Comment: I'd suggest you start with something a little simpler.  Perhaps coding a simple app to just load an image on the PC.  From there you can look at the myriad of ways of getting an image to another device such as posting to a common location (ftp server, web server, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely select something a little less difficult to start with.  As Chris said, hosting the file somewhere accessible by both tablet and PC would be your best bet to pull this off easily and quickly as a beginner.  One thing to keep in mind about what you're trying to do is how you're going to get the data from a to b.  After coming to a decision, formulate a question more finely tuned to what you're trying to do, and maybe you'll find better help.